# Перейти на view из контроллера

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте.

Есть следующая схема в Rails - контроллер `Operation` и два его `view` - `input` и `result`.
На `input` лежит форма, данные из которой `get`'ом отcылаются `result` и обрабатываются Operation#result для отображения на нём результата.

Необходимо в процессе обработки входных данных обнаружить их некорректность и отобразить либо ещё один `view` с сообщением об ошибке, либо - желательно - отобразить `input` с сообщением об ошибке (полагаю, можно отобразить `input`, послав ему `get` с параметрами ошибки и обработать параметры `get`'а при отображении этого `view`).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?..
Увы, пока даже не пока понять, как из метода контроллера отобразить другой `view`.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отсылать данные из формы get'ом неправильно.

```
if valid?
  render 'views/result'
else
  render 'views/input'
end
```

Comment: Спасибо за наводку.
Если я правильно понял, параметры `view` (для того, чтобы знать, отображать сообщение об ошибке или нет) можно передать через параметр-хэш options метода `render`?
А как к ним можно будет обратиться из `view`?

Comment: @shau-kote вы так и собираетесь rails изучать, наошупь? [Почитайте гид](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.14/layouts_and_rendering.html) хотя бы.